# How it works ??? Strange behavior of fstream

Tags: c++, c++11

Why `"fin >> baff"` changes `"res"` ???

```
char res[10000], buff[9];
int end, pos = 0;
ifstream fin( "input.txt");
fin.seekg( 0, ios::end);
end = (fin.tellg() / 8) - ( (fin.tellg() % 8 == 0) ? 0 : 1);
refresh( fin );
while( pos < end ){
    fin.seekg( pos*8, ios::beg);
    // this strange fin change my array res
    fin >> buff;
    refresh( fin );
    if ( buff[3] == '1') {
        if( buff[7] == '1') {
            res[pos++] = '1';
        } else if ( buff[7] == '0') {
            res[pos++] = '0';
        } else
            cout << "Error1" << endl;
    } else if ( buff[3] == '0') {
        res[pos++] = ' ';
    } else
        cout << "Error2";
    buff[8] = '\0';
    cout << buff << " " << pos << endl;
}
cout << "End of game" << endl;
ofstream fout("result.txt");
for ( int i = 0; i < pos; ++i)
    fout << res[i];
for ( int i = 0; i < pos; ++i)
    cout << res[i];
```

When i debug this code, on 3 iterations "fin >> buf" change my array "res", it's wery weird.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: How big is the data you are reading into `buf`?  It can only hold 9 characters and one of those needs to be the null terminator if you want a c-string.

Comment: Сode reads binary ASCII number and translates them to 0 or 1. For example 00110000 00110000 00110001 -> 001

Comment: What is `refresh(std::ifstream)`?

Comment: void refresh( ifstream &f) {
         f.close();
         f.open("input.txt");
     }

Comment: Thanks, the error was really in 'fin >> buff', i change it to 'fin.getline( buff, 9)' . Input data consisted of 3584 binary digits.

Comment: This may be a bit faster (no test for end of line delimiter) and clearer (no ambiguity about whether or not you're actually looking for end of lines): `fin.read(buff, 8); buff[8] = '\0';` English version: read 8 bytes into `buff` and then pop a null in the 9 th byte. You can also get rid of all of the scanning needed to find the length of the file. When you can't read 8 bytes, you bail.